# Is there an efficient way to return Array[Int] from a spark Dataframe without using collect()

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, collect

I have a dataframe something like this.

```
root
 |-- key1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value1: string (nullable = true)

+----+------+
|key1|value1|
+----+------+
|  E1|     1|
|  E3|     0|
|  E4|     1|
|  E2|     0|
...
+----+------+
```

And I convert `value1` column to `Array[Int]` by using `collect()` function as below. But this is not efficient solution, it takes 10-15 seconds. Because there are lots of data in the dataframe and in each spark streaming cycle, data is collected to the driver.

```
val data = Seq(("E1","1"),
      ("E3","0"),
      ("E4","1"),
      ("E2","0")
)

val columns = Seq("key1", "value1")
import spark.implicits._
val df = data.toDF(columns:_*)
val ordered_df = df.orderBy("key1").select("value1").collect().map(_(0)).toList
ordered_df.foreach(print)
```

> ```
> Output :
> 1001
> ```

So, what is the efficient way to return an array of Int from the above dataframe without using `collect()` function ?

Thanks,

Comment: There's no more efficient way. But do you really need to collect? What are you doing with the data afterwards? I'm assuming you don't just want to print them.

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient". `collect` is as efficient as it gets. Your data is actually distributed over multiple executor nodes. You then want to get it in an Array which resides in-momory on your driver node. Spark will get the data from worker nodes and create that array "very efficiently". Instead of "efficient" or "in-efficient", this is more of a "should" or "should not" question. Under normal (99.99 %) of cases, there is no good reason for you to want to do this.

Comment: I need to convert dataframe value column to Array because i will use this Array for analytic model input data. In streaming cycle, i consume 100-150 record in each cycle and for every record i will prepare this "Array" list and call pmml model with these inputs.